# How can i draw graph of Elliptic Curve mod p by using pari-gp?

Tags: graph, cryptography, pari-gp

Suppose E:y^2=x^3+Ax+B mod p, I have two questions?

1. how can I draw the graph of E with pari-gp.
2. how can I get the list of all points over the E.
   thank you for all.

Comment: Does SageMath is fine? [Graphically representing points on Elliptic Curve over finite field](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87545/18298). Listing all of the points is dangerous if `p` is a huge number.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse but  I wonder how it's done. Maybe there is a generator that generates all points without save them in a list

Answer (score 0):

**To define an [Elliptic Curve with SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.html) use**

```
E = EllipticCurve(GF(131),[0,1,0,1,0])
print(E)
```

and outputs

```
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + x^2 + x over Finite Field of size 131
```

In your case ( simplified Weierstrass from)

```
E = EllipticCurve(GF(p),[A,B])
```

will be enough.

**To plot a curve**

```
E.plot()
```

is enough

**To iterate the points**

```
for T in E.points():
    print(T)
```

is enough.

---

Try online on [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzVbBVcM3JySwoyUx2Li0qS9Vwd9MwNDbU1Ik20DHUAeNYTa6Cosy8Eg1XTS6utPwihRCFzDwFV72CfKBgsYamFZcCEECUhGhyASVy8ks0NAGb8hl_&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

[image]

And notice the symmetry!

### Pari-GP

From a [tutorial](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/Events/PARI2017c/talks/ecc_en.pdf)

```
a=ffgen(P,’a)
Es = ellinit([a^4,a^6],a);
```

Comment: thank you, i mean so how with pari-gp ? maybe someone can help

Comment: I've no knowledge about drawing with pari-GP